# Accelerometer ADXL345 e Blik LED

Tags: arduino

Olá desenvolvedores para Arduino.

Estou com uma dúvida ja tem algum tempo que não consigo resolver, vim aqui buscar alguma dica para a solucão desse meu problema.

Estou usando o Accelerometer ADXL345 para pegar a direção X_out e Y_out.

O intuito é fazer com que meu Led da esquerda entre na função de Pisca quando o valor X_out < -0.3 e fique em looping até que meu eixo Y_out seja superior a 0.3 e o mesmo quando meu eixo X_out for > 0.3, fazer com que o Led da esquerda acione.

*Usando o If, ele entra e sai da funcao, não mantendo meu Led piscando e assim saindo da funcao.
*Usando o While, ele entra na funcao mas por outro lado nao consigo retornar para resgatar o valor do Y_out.

Quem tiver alguma sugestao para aprimorar minha funcao seria válido.

Comecei o projeto baseado neste link do Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bys8pCuCDB8

```
    /*
    Arduino and ADXL345 Accelerometer Tutorial
     by Dejan, https://howtomechatronics.com
*/

#include <Wire.h>  // Wire library - used for I2C communication


int ADXL345 = 0x53; // The ADXL345 sensor I2C address

float X_out, Y_out, Z_out;  // Outputs

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // Initiate serial communication for printing the results on the Serial monitor
  Wire.begin(); // Initiate the Wire library
  // Set ADXL345 in measuring mode
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345); // Start communicating with the device 
  Wire.write(0x2D); // Access/ talk to POWER_CTL Register - 0x2D
  // Enable measurement
  Wire.write(8); // (8dec -> 0000 1000 binary) Bit D3 High for measuring enable 
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(100);


  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  // === Read acceleromter data === //
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345);
  Wire.write(0x32); // Start with register 0x32 (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(ADXL345, 6, true); // Read 6 registers total, each axis value is stored in 2 registers
  X_out = ( Wire.read()| Wire.read() << 8); // X-axis value
  X_out = X_out/256; //For a range of +-2g, we need to divide the raw values by 256, according to the datasheet
  Y_out = ( Wire.read()| Wire.read() << 8); // Y-axis value
  Y_out = Y_out/256;
  Z_out = ( Wire.read()| Wire.read() << 8); // Z-axis value
  Z_out = Z_out/256;

  Serial.print("Xa= ");
  Serial.print(X_out);
  Serial.print("   Ya= ");
  Serial.print(Y_out);
  Serial.print("   Za= ");
  Serial.println(Z_out);

  digitalWrite(8,HIGH);



  /*COMMENT*/


  while (X_out > 0.3) {

    keepRightBlink();    
  } 



     while (X_out < -0.3) {  

          keepLeftBlink();

          if(Y_out > -0.3){
           return ;
            } 
     }


}

int keepRightBlink(){
      digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
      delay(100);
      digitalWrite(7, LOW);
      delay(100);

}

int keepLeftBlink(){

      digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
      delay(100);
      digitalWrite(9, LOW);
      delay(100);

}
```